# I have problem when run react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

Today the app work correctly and the next day i have next error: unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. 
I want to know why this error occurs from one day to the next?

Comment: Have you changed anything in the code? Are you using VSC? Are you working in a team (maybe someone pushed something that broke the code)? Have you ran `npm/yarn install` which could have installed different dep versions if they weren't pinned? Also, paste the whole traceback/error, the exact command you are invoking and versions of RN you are using. You need to provide more details for such question to be answerable.

Comment: Try to close all running windows and remove node modules folder from you proect root directory and try to re install node modules using npm install --save

Comment: Thank! the solution was running rm -r node_modules an reinstall npm install